# Equivalent Java JNA API to Windows Get-NetIPAddress command

Tags: java, jna

I have a requirement to read Window's system all Network Interfaces static IPV4 IPs (Irrespective of the Network Interface state up/down) and the **Get-NetIPAddress** ps command retrieves all the static IPs in the windows system even if the interfaces are disconnected from network. This **Get-NetIPAddress** command is the solution since ipconfig command does not show static IPs of interfaces which are down. I need to get this information from Java. I looked into the Java JNA API documentation [here](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/) and I could not find the relevant API which calls this command to give me all the static IPs.

I would like to know if there is any Java JNA Api which calls **Get-NetIPAddress** command already? 
If it is not supported yet, can I get help how to extend JNA to write my own API to use the **Get-NetIPAddress** command from Java and achieve this ? 
(We can achieve this using JNI and C++ code but I want to use JNA to achieve this)

Comment: I'm curious what information you don't get from [`java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces()) in core Java?   Alternately, I have contributed WMI code to JNA that will give you the same information from `wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter` which might also provide the IPs you want.

Comment: Also the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` WMI class may be helpful.  Again, I can point you to JNA code that does all the COM overhead in Java to query WMI if you need it, but check the commandline first to make sure it gives you the list you want.

Comment: If you post the C/C++ code I can help suggest the JNA to port it.

Comment: For the interface a static IPV4 IP is set and when the ethernet is down or ethernet is pulled out then "java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()" and "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" both does not print this static IP associated with the interface. Since static IP is configured, even when the interface's state is "Network cable unplugged" in adaptor settings I want to retrieve the static IP from Java and only the "Get-NetIPAddress" powershell command works and prints this static IP. Hence I want to call this "Get-NetIPAddress" from Java and use the output. Please share your thoughts

Comment: Well you can always use the `exec()` command to run a command in the console.  [This class](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/master/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/util/ExecutingCommand.java) should help.  Just call `ExecutingCommand.runNative("powershell -Command Get-NetIPAddress")`

Comment: Or use the [jPowerShell](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell) library.

Comment: Requirement is to call from Java JNA/JNI and not use exec() with powershell command. That is why I am looking for Java JNA equivalent API. First option is to get JNA API and if it is not available we have to write our own JNI. This is the reason I am looking out for the "Get-NetIPAddress" powershell command JNA equivalent API if available or I need help in extending and writing the JNA API myself using this command

Comment: Again, if you can show me C code you're working from I can help you with JNA. Otherwise your question is too vague.